# changing url using redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following problem in my htaccess file

The following url

`a-b/c/d` has to be redirected to `a/b/char-c`

```
RewriteRule ^(annunci/a\-[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*)$ char-$1  [R=301]
```

How can i solve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

> `a-b/c/d has to be redirected to a/b/char-c`

Use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)?/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/-]*)/?$ /$1/$2-$3/$4/$2-$5/ [L,R=302]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
RewriteRule ([^/]+)?/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(delta)/?$ /$1/$2-$3/$4/$2-$5/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Can you explain what does it mean? i dont't understand all the parts of this code

Comment: and what about this solution? search in the url for string "str-ing"...everytime you find this, update this with suffix-string. The suffix is fixed, only the string change, where the string that change was the str-ing in the old url.

Comment: Not getting your comments now. Did you try this answer? What was outcome?

Comment: because if the url doesnt' match actual url you are redirected to a generic url it doesn't show me messages of any sort (or maybe that i can't understand)

Comment: I don't see my suggested rule in your .htaccess

Comment: it's written in row 16

Comment: Ok and what is the full URL did you try to test this rule?

Comment: from

alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/delta/ 

to

alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta/

Comment: Now it's a lot better, the only thing that it doesn't find is the $5...why?

Comment: I have tested exactly with `/alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/delta/` URI and it became `/alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta/`

Comment: I can't guess without seeing your full URL that you are using to test it.

Comment: I can't publish the url because otherwise google will put in the results...can i send it to you in other way?

Comment: You can email me on `anubhava@aol.com`

Comment: Can you transform this ([^/-]*) part into a fixed section? for example .../deltaone, .../deltatwo, etc? like this ([^/]+)?/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/deltaone/?$ /$1/$2-$3/$4/fixed-caseone/ [L,R=302] etc? if i do like this, in my situation the url go back to $4/

Comment: Yes you can try: `RewriteRule ([^/]+)?/(deltaone)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/-]*)/?$ /$1/$2-$3/$4/$2-$5/ [L,R=302]`

Comment: can i do the same for ([^/-]*) ? it gives me error (deltaone)

Comment: It is very difficult to understand now what you're trying to do. I have tried my best to help you out but these comments are are getting no where.

Comment: Anubhava thanks but the only thing that i want to do is to redirect from this url ([^/]+)?/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(deltaone)/?$ to that url alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta. the problem is that when i substitute this part ([^/-]*) with (deltaone) it gives me error. so i wanted to ask you if you can substitute ([^/]+) as for ([^/-]*) with (deltaone).

Comment: But in this URI `/alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta` which part is `deltaone`?

Comment: in this uri, deltaone is delta

Comment: now if i type alfa/fixed-beta/gamma i'm redirected to alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta. if i type alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/delta i'm redirected to alfa/fixed-beta/gamma

Comment: Make sure my rule is **the first rule in your .htaccess**. With that rule in place it redirects `/alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/delta/` to `/alfa/fixed-beta/gamma/fixed-delta/`

Comment: it doesn't function. i don't know how.